# Android Studio Emulator Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run an app, the emulator never gets past the Android logo. After a few minutes or so, this message would appear - emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in 'list0@���'.

There was another post about this on stack overflow and someone suggested: "set front camera to emulated and back camera to none". I tried that and the same error is still there. (This may or may not be related to the problem, but I've already tried increasing RAM and heap size.)

Does anyone know what this error means or have suggestions as to how to fix this?

Here is a link to an image showing the issue I'm talking about: 
[emulator: ERROR: _factory_client_recv: Unknown camera factory query name in 'list0@���'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBDFr.png)

Comment: Have you tried creating a new emulator?

Comment: I just made a new emulator. I don't see the error anymore, but it's back to my original problem where the emulator never gets past the Android logo.

Comment: Do you have a computer with a quick enough processor and enough ram to run the emulator? One of my friends that has a computer which takes about 10 minutes to fully boot the emulator.

Comment: it's a mac air (processor 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5). doesn't take long for the device to show up (probably no more than a minute) and gets stuck at the android logo.

Comment: Have you tried leaving it to load for a while?

Comment: yes, it times out after 5 minutes. and the emulator closes. i try again and same thing

Comment: What is your VM application heap size? Go to AVD Manager, find your AVD, click Edit (the pencil icon), then click Advanced Settings, scroll down to "Memory and Storage", and look where it says "VM Heap". Make sure this is at least 32 MB.

Comment: RAM is 1GB, VM Heap is 2GB, Internal Storage is 800MB

Comment: My VM heap is only 64MB... I'm wondering if yours is too big for your computer. Try changing your VM heap size to only 64MB and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with same messages . I resolved it by wiping the data off the emulator through Android Virtual Device Manger. Other settings - I had the Emulator GPU ticked and Front & Back Camera set as none. 
[image: AVDM option to Wipe Emulator Data]